# Improper project stucture when i am pulling from git repository

Tags: eclipse, git

We have a project on a main branch in git repo.When i am pulling the project,the project structure is not coming properly.

[image]

And also is it necessary to store Eclipse-IDE specific file like .project in Git repo?
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: ...what's wrong with the project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem that i was missing the .classpath file as we have not committed the .classpath file to git repository.So when i have taken the fresh clone of the repository that time i was missing my classpath file.So just added it and the problem solved.Another alternative is to go on to the Build path add the file to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely free what files you store in your git repository.

Whatever you commit in whatever directory will be visible the same way in the same structure after a clone.

If there seem to be differences on the committing side and the cloned side, have a look at `git status` - maybe you did not commit all your files.

Answer (score 0):

You have no need to store the .project file in your git repository as it is very specific to eclipse and store all the project related information for that particular workspace.

You can also add this file into the `.gitignore` file , that will tell git to ignore this file while doing a commit. In this way you can avoid checking in of file that you intentionally don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may have absolute paths to the source files. If the location of the files is not the absolute same as on the computer where you committed, the project won't be able to find the files.

Try right-click -> Properties on a file that cannot be found, and lookup the "Path" and "Location" properties. Location may be absolute, but Path should not.